# How can I select a row that may contain swapped fields?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

How can I select one row from that table https://i.stack.imgur.com/27cu9.jpg where values of 'user_1' and 'user_2' may look like

```
user_1 user_2
  1      2
  2      1
```

In other words I want to select a field that contains 2 users with submitted=1 no matter in which field the value is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple query that does this:

```
select *
from t
where submitted = 1 and 2 in (user_1, user_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, I think you need to `JOIN` the table on itself if you are trying to return rows that have corresponding users (1,2) and (2,1):

```
select t1.*
from yourtable t1 
   join yourtable t2 on 
       t1.user_1 = t2.user_2 and t1.user_2 = t2.user_1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ae4c/1)

If however you are just trying to see if user 2 exists in either of the fields, then look at Gordon's post.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
       select * from tblname as t1, tblname as t2 where 
       t1.user_1 = t2.user_2 and t1.user_2 = t2.user_1 and t1.user_1<>t1.user_2
```

EDIT:-

Updated the query so that the rows with the same values do not appear in the result.